# Is there any way to track covid 19 confirmed cases by zipcode or addresses API

Tags: healthkit

I would like to know if there is any API outhere with specific information about confirming cases that you could filter by zipcode or addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake currently doesn't contain data by zip code or address. We do, however, have FIPS codes for some OutbreakLocations as described in the documentation: https://c3.ai/covid-19-api-documentation/#tag/OutbreakLocation

We'll look at including this type of data in the data lake.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an API, but the [Johns Hopkins github data](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) goes down to the country -> state -> county levels.

You can write a chronjob to trigger a daily `git pull` and maintain your own locally updated data repo of sorts.

Other helpful code you might like: You can use the following code provided by [covid19calc.org](https://covid19calc.org/python_preprocess.py) to help roll it up to various levels of aggregation. Note this pulls data from the most recent day in the data set. Check the IO_Serializer code for more specifics.